# Cocos2d 2.x: I Can't Seem To Chang The Launch Image For The 3GS! Its Still Showing The Cocos2d Orange Default Image

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, cocos2d-iphone, launchimage

**Problem**

My builds are retaining the Cocos2d template Launch Images.

I've searched every inch of the project folder, there are no cocos2d Launch imaged remaining

**Expected Result**

For each of the correct sized artworks to appear in each compatible iOS devices.

**My Steps**

I made my own artwork and have resized and made all necessary sizes using Adobe Illustrator (so I know my dimensions are correct).

I then imported them (copied) in to my project, then gone through the painstaking process of naming them all correctly.

Launching on a real 3GS, I'm still getting the cocos2d Splash screen.

**I've tried**

1) Deleting the build off the 3GS,

2) Resetting factory defaults on my 3gs

Note:...At this point I can't be expecting my customers to have to do any of this should I choose to change my artwork in the future

3) Product/Clean... But this doesn't help. A while back someone advised me to press a key combination to do a different kind of clean. Maybe this is what I need to do?

**Potential Problems**

I have noticed in the past with certain resources that if they change outside of the program the build process must use some cached version of the file? I noticed when I altered a TMX tile mapm in the program called 'Tiled', that with Xcode closed, the changes I had made were not present in the next rebuild of the game. I had to delete the file from the project, and copy it back in forcing it to reprocess the file. It felt like a hack.

Comment: Couple of ideas that may help (kinda poking in the dark here): 1) did you add the artwork you made to the correct Target? If not, the files won't be copied to the device. 2) manually delete the Derived Data: open Organizer, select your project, click the Delete Button. Sometimes just cleaning the project may not be enough in my experience.

Comment: I just cleared the Derived Data, that has not changed anything. I've never experimented with the benefits of multiple targets, and don't really understand what they are or how do do anything with them? So I'm guessing it downs apply to me, but would like further advice incase it might help...?

nevertheless, I still need to fix this issue...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just accidentally fixed it, and thought I'd share in detail because its one of those hidden problems.

I had searched the net previously to find the required file names and the appropriate dimensions.

- Default.png (320x480)
- Default@2x.png (640x960)
- Default-568@2x.png (640x1136)

However, this was apparently not enough. DESPITE the fact that the Launch Images section of the project in Xcode showed that I had added them all, and didn't complain that any were missing....

**The solution** was to:

1. Remove the images from the project via Finder, and keep them safe in a separate folder.
2. Rename them to something obscure and unrelated
3. Drag the file back into the project, copy if needed.
4. Goto the Project/Launch Images section, and then click the little folders and select the appropriate image for each line.

Xcode will offer to automatically rename the file for you to an appropriate name for the builder.

This filed the problem for me, and I'm going to do the same for the other images just to ensure that its clean.

The thing that worries me is that I searched everywhere for that cocos2d image, and i couldn't find it ANYWHERE... Where was it hiding?

Even thought I'm answering my own question, I'm hoping it will help someone else in the future. If you think I did a good job, vote me up to build up my rep. thanks everyone!